# Entity Framework. Insert Or Update в одном SQL-запросе из-за Триггера

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, update, триггер

Есть база данных MS SQL Server, в ней две таблицы: Таблица1, Таблица2.
Есть логика на c# с использованием Entity Framework, где создается контекст базы данных, затем производится запись в Таблицу1 (новая запись), и затем запись в Таблицу2 (новая или обновление). Затем вызывается (context.SaveChanges()). Все работало отлично.

Но в некоторых базах данных, в зависимости от потребностей клиентов устанавливаются клиентские триггеры, которые выполняют какие-то автоматизации клиентов, в зависимости от потребностей клиентов.

Тут выяснилось, что некоторые триггеры создают проблемы, а именно: триггер установлен на первую таблицу на операции (INSERT,UPDATE) и проверяет некоторые значения записываемых данных и если они соответствуют условию, создает или обновляет запись в Таблица2. В довесок логика добавляет новую запись в Таблицу2, хотя должна была уже ее лишь обновить.

В результате в Таблице2 создаются две записи, вместо одной – из триггера и из логики, что не должно происходить. Логика должна как то определить, что запись уже существует. В моем представлении, EF должен сгенерировать запрос на Insert или Update в одном SQL-выражении (IF EXISTS (..) UPDATE.. ELSE INSERT)

Как этого добиться на уровне EF? Спасибо.

Comment: Как предположение: сначала сделать Insert, а потом уже insert or update для второй таблицы (да, будет два вызова SaveChanges).

Comment: [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#triggers), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes#sql-server-tables-with-triggers-or-certain-computed-columns-now-require-special-ef-core-configuration), [3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/misc) - не?